# PHP doesn't work. What does the intepreter/compiler mean my script is not a regular file?

Tags: php

Okay, I am just trying to get it to work.  I keep getting the following error message:

CGIWrap Error: Execution of this script not permitted

Execution of (exercise5) is not permitted for the following reason:

Script is not a regular file

Server Data:

```
Server Administrator/Contact: system@nova.umuc.edu 
Server Name: nova.umuc.edu 
Server Port: 80 
Server Protocol: HTTP/1.1 
Virtual Host: nova.umuc.edu
```

Request Data:

```
User Agent/Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( ) 8868058803 system:4.02190 JobsSearchToolbar/1.2 
Request Method: GET 
Remote Address: 209.183.235.178 
Remote Port: 19687 
Extra Path Info: /new2.php
```

It is rather infuriating.  Please see my below simple code.  What am I doing wrong guys??  HELP??!!??

This is my code:

```
           #!/usr/local/bin/php

           <?php
             print "hello, world"   
           ?>

           <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

           <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head>
           </head>
           <body>
           </body>
           </html>
```

This is my link:
http://nova.umuc.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/ct386a28/exercise5/new2.php

Is it me or is it actually easier to code "stuff" sometimes than to actually configure it? I dunno. . .

Comment: The error messages say little about your server type. Normally PHP is used with mod_php and does not require to be located in the cgi-bin/ directory. If you have to do so, give that script a `.cgi` extension over `.php`, make it executable, and remove the leading spaces in the first line before `#!/usr/bin/..`

Comment: "Getting" how? What are you doing when you receive this error? How do you receive it?

Comment: I'd talk to your UMUC.EDU IT guys, personally. This is something specific to your [somewhat unusual] server configuration for scripts.

Comment: Your link indicates that you're using this system to submit a homework assignment ("exercise 5" for... some course at the University of Maryland University College), which makes it off topic for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically after talking tech support, I realized that Filezilla was uploading the files as binary instead of ASCII.

I actually had to go log into the NOVA Unix server and change the file using: `dos2unix new2.php new2.php`.  Once I did that, it worked. It had nothing to do with programming; it was all config stuff.